# How can i take the element i want with SQL?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

| time | staffID |
| --- | --- |
| 02-21 9:10:23 | 1 |
| 02-21 9:10:24 | 1 |
| 02-21 9:10:27 | 1 |
| 02-21 9:11:13 | 3 |
| 02-21 9:11:14 | 3 |
| 02-21 9:12:19 | 4 |
| 02-21 9:12:33 | 4 |
| 02-21 9:12:35 | 4 |
| 02-21 9:13:49 | 2 |
| 02-21 9:13:51 | 2 |
| 02-21 9:13:53 | 2 |
| 02-21 9:13:55 | 2 |
| 02-21 9:13:57 | 2 |

i wanna get the each staff value in the early one
like

| time | StaffId |
| --- | --- |
| 02-21 9:10:23 | 1 |
| 02-21 9:11:13 | 3 |
| 02-21 9:12:19 | 4 |
| 02-21 9:13:49 | 2 |

i have no idea about it, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select min(time) as time
, Staffid
from MyTable
group by Staffid
```